# Why does Oledb Connection.Close() take far too long to execute?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

During development of a desktop app to connect to a local database, I moved the database to a network location and now every time I call Connection.Close() the program hangs for 5-15 seconds. I would see this problem very infrequently when the database was stored on the local computer, but now that it's on the network, it hangs almost every time I attempt a Close(). The first call I make to the database I don't even query it, it's just a test connection that I open and close to make sure the user can connect, but it still hangs far too long.

I've seen this question asked before, but no one can offer a suggestion or solution to fix other than 'try using() {} to have c# clean it up.' This does not affect the Close() time in any way.

Is there an option in the connection string to address this issue? Does anyone know why this is happening?

The connection string I use is:

```
CONNECTION_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\\NEWTORK\Shared\Database\Database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"

private void

  Form_Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection();
    Connection.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
    try
    {
      Console.Write("Connection Opening.....");
      Connection.Open();
      Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");
      Console.Write("Writing Status Text.....");
      lbl_Status.Text = "Online";
      Console.WriteLine("Written Status Text");
      Console.Write("Connection Closing.....");
      Connection.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed");
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
      lbl_Status.Text = "Offline";
      lbl_Status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
      MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to Database");
    }
  }
```

In my output window, I see the opening messages and the writing status messages right away, but the app hangs just before the 'Console.Write("Connection Closing.....");' line. After 5-15 seconds, the close message appears in the window.

There are many connections in the app that do query the database and it seems to hang just before trying to close all of them as well. I do seems to notice that repeating the same query without closing the app sometimes results in quicker close times for the repeated close, but it always hangs during the first attempt for any query.

Comment: Put code into a BackGroundWorker so form doesn't hang. I've done this lots of times.

Comment: @jdweng I have never used a BackGroundWorker before, so chances are I did something incorrectly. I added one to this code, and while it did allow the form to show before the original connection was closed, it also allowed me to attempt a login to the app which also opens a connection to the database and threw an exception because it was trying to open an new connection before the previous one was closed.

Comment: @G. Maniatis You need to wait until the BackgroundWorker is done, by using the `.RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working for me:
When I was getting long lag times for the Connection.Close() method, I was using the Microsoft Access database engine 2016 (x64). For an unrelated reason, I needed to uninstall the 2016 engine and go with the 2010 (x86) version. Now my Connection.Close() times are averaging ~40 ms which is perfectly acceptable for my application.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any pending transactions between the database and the program, then `Close()` will roll them back. It also has to request and drop it from the connection pool, which could take longer on a remote drive. Could this be your issue?

[Here are the docs on the method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.close?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_OleDb_OleDbConnection_Close)

To solve this, you could use a BackgroundWorker to execute it, like so:

```
var b = new BackgroundWorker();
b.DoWork += CloseDB;
b.RunWorkerCompleted += someMethodAfterClose;
b.RunWorkerAsync();
```

CloseDB:

```
public void CloseDB(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    someConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to check for any pending transactions. The docs are not very helpful in that regard. I tried to implement a BackGroundWorker, but it was unsuccessful. I could get the form to show right away after loading, but the connection still hangs while the background worker waits for it and in the mean time I can do another database query which throws an exception because the connection is not closed yet. I could try `RunWorkerCompleted` like @jdweng suggested, but that doesn't solve the delay issue then, so I'm back right where I started.

Comment: All you need to do is use the `.RunWorkerCompleted` to wait until it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Often this can be the server settings. If the firewall + windows defender is active, then it scans all "file" accessing - the result is very slow opens, and of course close().

Try running the computer where the shared folder resides with firewall and windows defender turned off. I seen this often fix the large delays. Of course, using a socket based technology would eliminate this issue (eg: server  based). However, you have what you have, and often it is not your code speed, but the "windows file" system, and that of network and anti-virus software that is the cause of this slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

This might get flagged as "not an answer", but I have this problem as well, and no one seems to have found the real explanation, so instead of creating a redundant question, here are some of my symptoms:

- Started happening much more often when the office updated to Windows 10 (from Windows 7).
- Happens frequently but not always.  Sometimes the OleDb connection close/dispose is very quick, sometimes it hangs ~10-15 s. The variation is seemingly random for any given connection attempt at any time, even with the same Access database, same machine, and same process.
- Hanging can happen for databases located both locally and on network, though haven't tested if one is more frequent than the other.
- Happens even if connection makes no changes or transactions (i.e. just SELECT queries).
- Happens only with OleDb connections, i.e., a user opening and closing database via the Access interface is fine.

**Update**

In desperation, I tried the suggestion of closing the connection in a background thread, to avoid holding up the main thread during this process.  But when I did that, whenever a subsequent connection was initiated later on, got this error:

*Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt*

Googling indicates this seems to happen with many people when dealing with Access database connections, but often for unknown reasons.

So I tried a different suggestion of changing conn string to include `OLE DB Services=-1;`.  This appeared to fix issue at first.  No expert on this, far as I can tell it basically avoids the hanging-on-close problem by leaving some of the connection's resources open behind the scenes for reuse, even after disposing the conn object.  Fine with me...except eventually it appears to close those resources (probably some timeout), and then when a connection is later made, back to the inexplicable `AccessViolationException` above.

**Potential Solution**

From piecing together various web comments and my own experimentation:

- OleDb does not play nice with multi-threading.
- Closing the *last* open Access connection in an app, no matter what database, seems to trigger the unloading of some resources inside the OleDb library itself, hence this is a potentially time-consuming operation.

So what I did, add an empty Access database hidden inside my app, and on startup open an OleDb connection to it.  I do NOT dispose the connection and maintain reference to the connection to keep it from closing on its own.  That way, any  disposing of subsequent connections never trigger the unloading of whatever resources OleDb is keeping around.

It's a hack but so far this appears to fix the original problem.

Of course the *real* answer is avoid Access databases!